# Psd slice and creazing new design in atk4

Tags: atk4, psd

What is the best way to create totally new design for my atk4 application.  I have psd files, but i'm not sure if I convert psd to html grid system or some other, what are the best practices?

Also, when i have html, what and how i implement html in atk4, so that atk4 is still upgradable?

thanks, Peter

Comment: I guess it's quite easy in ATK 4.2.5. Just create HTML and put some parts in ATK template tags. You shouldn't have problems upgrading ATK. BUT, you'll anyway have problems with upcoming ATK 4.3 version because CSS is mostly moved out of ATK to separate atk-template project which of course should be compatible with ATK, but also can be used without it.

Comment: do i cut html in 960 grid system? Is there any roadplan, when the 4.3 will be roling out?

Comment: As far as I know there is now exact plan when 4.3 will be ready for official roll out, but you can already download it from github (4.3 branch) and try out. About design stuff I'll not be wise enough to advice you something. Let's wait, maybe Romans, Dmitry or someone else will answer this question.

Comment: Its nice that there is exact plan when 4.3 will be ready for official roll out, but i dont't find it anywhere?

Comment: Sorry I had a typo in my previous comment. "... is now exact plan ..." should be "... is NOT exact plan ..." :) Sorry for confusion.

Comment: but definitely that'll happen this year :) maybe after 2-3 months.

Comment: hehe, Ok, i will count after summer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to go:

1) you create your own html/css, based on your psd templates. move that under templates/default/ int o shared.html and in css/img as necessary. add also js_include and other tags that are required to bootup jui interface for atk4

2) alternatively, especially if you plan to use atk4.3, you can setup all your layout using views, boxes and styles that are available out of the box, only adding custom assets and finetuning the color layout using less builder. New css capabilities can be seen here: http://css.agiletoolkit.org

Normally, we stick to (2) for intranet solutions or where minor design tweaks are required. If your layout is very custom, go with (1), as it gives you full freedom.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. If you dont mind, i have two more, first how much time would app with 3 custom layouts with custom forms and a lot of standard elements take to connect al the dots for point one, and on the other end when will the 4.3 be ready to production use? Thank you very much!

Comment: Would need to see those layouts. But i reckon 1-2 weeks to cut, integrate and finetune. Really depends how skilled the cutter is and how well views are developed

Comment: He, we have first problem. We created new html for button and set it like this:  $form->add("Button",null,null,array('loginbtn')). That is ok. but the button produced still comes tžwith a lot of classes: class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only". Where can we remove these classes and put our own?

Comment: if i try removeClass or addClass it just breaks, with errors like: Cannot append to tag class...

Comment: I suggest you start a new question on stackoverflow.

Comment: Just a note - 4.3 CSS is still in development and the tags are pretty volatile. You can follow it on https://github.com/atk4/agiletoolkit-css/